# Building search function with knockout using multiple viewmodels

Tags: knockout.js

I Have 2 View Models for my search function, the first view model contains 2 observable's, the search string and the search type. The second view model is the result based on the search. In my Ajax post I use the Search Type And Search string as variables to obtain the desired result. But I get the following error***Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Customers is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: Customers*** because the customers array has not been initialized, I apply the bindings for my Second View Model based on search button click.
Here is A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/CZaZU/) To explain better what I am trying to do.

Here is my complete javascript code segment:

```
  var CustomerSearchViewModel = {
        SearchType: ko.observable(""),
        SearchString: ko.observable(""),
        setSearchType: function (data, element) {
            this.SearchType($(element.target).val());
        }
    }

    var CustomerSearhResultViewModelDS = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.CustomerID = ko.observable(data.CustomerID);
        alert(self.CustomerID);
        self.CustomerName = ko.observable(data.CustomerName);
        self.CustomerEMail = ko.observable(data.CustomerEMail);
        self.CustomerTelephone = ko.observable(data.CustomerTelephone);
        self.CustomerCompanyName = ko.observable(data.CustomerCompanyName);
        self.CustomerCompanyAddress1 = ko.observable(data.CustomerCompanyAddress1);
        self.CustomerCompanyAddress2 = ko.observable(data.CustomerCompanyAddress2);
        self.CustomerCompanyZipCode = ko.observable(data.CustomerCompanyZipCode);
    }


    var CustomerSearhResultViewModel = function (Customer) {
        var self = this;

        self.Customers = ko.observableArray(Customer);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Services/DataServicesECOM.svc/CustomerSearch",
            data: { SearchType: CustomerSearchViewModel.SearchType(), SearchString: CustomerSearchViewModel.SearchString() },
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedCustomer =
              $.map(Result.d,
             function (item) {
                 return new CustomerSearhResultViewModelDS(item);
             }
               );
             self.Customers(MappedCustomer);
                $('#ModalDetail').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    };

    function ActivateSearch() {
        var VM = new CustomerSearhResultViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(CustomerSearchViewModel);
    });
```

Comment: you have many mistakes here and you question is not very clear.you can not even rebind again a same model you can just update or map it.Please be a litle more clear with you question what you want and what is the problem you tried debugging?

Comment: See edit, Added fiddle too to try and explain better.

Comment: why you doing this in two different model when it can be done in one model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to be binding each view model to different parts of the page. See [Render partial view using knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597544/render-partial-view-using-knockout-js/14600067#14600067) for how to do that.

Secondly, you need to be initialising an empty search results view model on page load, and binding that to the page section you want, then *update* that view model once you have results.

As an aside, when your view model has the exact same properties as your data model, I'd use the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) rather that manually copying the data over.