# Knockout - How to set a child ViewModel property on main page ViewModel after loading a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to dynamically load the content of a div on my main page, with a partial view returned from the controller.  The content of that div may change depending on which button the user clicks on the main view.  The partial views have their own knockout viewmodels, which I want to bind to the div (or a sub div within the partial view).

This is what I have tried...

I have a main knockout ViewModel on my main page...

```
window.mainpage.viewmodel = (function (ko, datacontext) {
    var self = this;

    self.someValue = ko.observable("test value");
    self.childViewModel = ko.observable();

    return {
       someValue: someValue,
       childViewModel: childViewModel
    };
})(ko, window.mainpage.datacontext);  

$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = window.mainpage.viewmodel;
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Then my view has two divs, one bound to someValue and another bound to the childViewModel....

```
<div data-bind="text: someValue"></div>
<div id="subContent" data-bind="with: childViewModel">
</div>
```

When I click on a button on the form, I want it to set the content of the "subContent" div to the result of a Partial View controller action...

```
$('#subContent').load('/Test/GetPage', data, function (response, status, xhr) {
                 //Do something when the partial view is loaded in #subContent
            });
```

My PartialView has its own ViewModel, which I have declared in its own js file, which is declared within the partial view....

```
window.child.subviewmodel = (function (ko, datacontext) {
    var self = this;

    self.someChildValue = ko.observable("test child value");

    return {
       someChildValue: someChildValue
    };

})(ko, window.child.datacontext);
```

My problem is where to create my child ViewModel and how to assign it to the childViewModel property on the main ViewModel.

Also, what should I do to ensure that the memory usage gets cleared properly each time I reload the sub content?

Can anyone suggest the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would advise against tightly coupling your viewmodels like this (by reference) and would suggest that you establish a communication channel instead using some kind of event aggregator ([knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/) for example)
2. You should create your child VM as soon as the DOM for your child view has been loaded.
3. ko.cleanNode() is your friend

Comment: I think what's making it tricky for me is that my child view can change depending on the current context.  i.e. there is logic in the controller action that determines which of a number of partial views to return.  I'm trying to make it so that only those partial views are aware of their own viewmodel type.

Comment: So when I call $('#subContent').load, at that point I am not aware of which type of viewmodel to create.

Comment: Let the subview bootstrap its own viewmodel. Don't forget that you aren't limited to plain HTML when dynamically loading view fragments.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I have now done that and it seems to work fine....  i.e. I have added  $(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(window.child.subviewmodel, $('#pageRoot').get(0));
    });       to a <script> tag at the top of my partial view

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have a child model here, or could you work with two models and bind them to different parts of the page? If so, you can use this answer to help you do that:

[Render partial view using knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597544/render-partial-view-using-knockout-js/14600067#14600067)

And if your models need to communicate with each other, you can implement a pub/sub pattern for that:

[Variable Dependency with knockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555381/variable-dependency-with-knockoutjs/14559492#14559492)